# Cannot connect to internet using D-link mobile broadband modem for BSNL network

Tags: 12.04, networking, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am using dlink modem of model DWM-156 as an HSUPA USB adapter with a BSNL network sim in it. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 alongside with windows7. I have defined the network settings in the mobile broadband category. I can connect to the internet on windows7 but while using ubuntu I cannot connect to internet. Upon typing

`lsusb`

in the terminal, I found that the dlink device is detected by Ubuntu.

Also I am not provided with any CD for installation of drivers and the modem has no .deb files in it.

And most importantly Ubuntu is not detecting the memory card inside the card reader of my modem.

What should I do to get myself connected to the internet?

Comment: have you set up the DSL connection for it?

Comment: Yes I have setted up. For all devices in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)first eject the windows driver CD of your modem from "terminal" or from "DISKS" (default,not automatic), then you can connect modem through network manager.

2)or use the software or .deb file provided with the modem (automatic, not default, not through network manager(nw) & you cannot use software center).

I advice to use the first one as it provides extra options like SMS, USSD, contacts, info, scan for networks through modem manager gui .

you can add your device id to usb mode switch for automatic eject as soon as you plugin your modem [click here to add your device to usb mode switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487004/how-to-add-d-link-dwm-156-to-usb-switch-mode-for-automatic-eject-of-driver-cd)

Hope this will help U

**it is not real CD, just a popup memmory within the modem.**.

problem is that ubuntu defaultly allows you to use the nw not the .deb file provided by the manufacturer(so your driver CD is not allowed mounted on unity defaultly), for they use usb mode switch to eject the unmounted CD, which does not have id of your modem which is newer one to market [click here to add your device to usb mode switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487004/how-to-add-d-link-dwm-156-to-usb-switch-mode-for-automatic-eject-of-driver-cd).

using default method is benefit only to users but newer modem gets unidentified and they have to manually add their device id to usb mode switch.

ubuntu 14.04 have updated list & it will automatically eject & you will your see your connection at nw.

Hope this helps U & please leave a comment

Comment: The key problem is that my modem is not reorganized in Ubuntu. But I found it listed in typing the -lsusb command.

Ubuntu does not even show the memory card within my modem. It does not reorganize my device.

Also I am not provided with a CD and there is no .deb files.

Comment: oh! no it is the driver CD which is inside the modem itself.You can  never see it.It is not the real CD, it is just the piece of popup memory which loads the windows programme software for the first time you insert it into the windows os & if you had already installed it in windows it will disappear

Comment: only you can use your modem after you eject CD from modem through disks (you can find option at top right side/ triangle above a line).it will says 'eject the medium of drive' if you move cursor on to it. memory card also shown only after ejecting it. you can  type eject in terminal to remove it.

Comment: the process of ejection is not permanent.so you are not doing any thing wrong.if you unplug and again connect modem again you have to eject it again for use as amodem or a memory card reader. you have to add your device id to usb mode switch for automatic eject .

Comment: modem will be speeder for net access in ubuntu than windows because ubuntu is using internal drivers.mounting of driverCD is disabled in unity ubuntu by default ,so to get the .deb file you have to plug into other desktop environments within ubuntu/other linux oses. using .deb file will be slower as in windows as it is a external driver.you can also uninstall .deb file once you installed it ubuntu through terminal command. in general ubuntu users have two way of connecting modems to internet than single way windows.note:.deb file do not provide SMS,USSD,trafic,contacts,call functions asin win